# Vectors are linearly independent if the rref of their matrix has columns of leading ones

Tags: linear-algebra

Say I choose the vectors (1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,1,0), these are clearly not linearly independent, but the matrix the form is [1,0,0;0,1,1;0,0,0], which has leading ones in every column, or have I made a mistake somewhere?

Here is the proof:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have made a mistake (in interpretation).  Your RREF doesn't have $3$ pivots:  it only has $2$.  The reason:   you're vectors span a $2$-dimensional space.

Answer (score 0):

There is no leading one (“pivot”) in the last column. The only nonzero entry has another nonzero entry to its left, so is quite clearly not the leading entry for that row.

Comment: Yes, but is it not a leading one in the column? As it is the first element of the column, and it is a one.

Comment: @4M4D3U5M0Z4RT “Leading” refers to the position in the row. Otherwise, one would conclude that $\small{\pmatrix{1&1\\0&0}}$ has full rank, which is patently absurd. Review the definitions of these terms.